# Python check if string is in document

Tags: python, string, file, search

I have a piece of code that should check if you can find a string in an text file. Here is my code:

```
i=0
list=[value0, value1, etc.]
while i<25:
    y=str(list[i])
    x= "*A X  "+y
    print(x)
    with open('C:\directory\file.txt','r') as file:
        if x in file.readlines():
            print("true")
        else:
            print("false") 
    i+=1
```

In the output none of the values are printed true. Whereas the search text is present in the file.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Hi Elias, welcome to stackoverflow! Have made some edits in your question. Also, do post your output next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python `readlines()` function returns an array of lines.

You can use the `read()` function to read the entire file and search for value in it.

```
with open('C:\directory\file.txt','r') as file:
    if x in file.read():
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `file.readlines()` to `file.read()`.

`file.readlines()` returns list of lines so checking if `x in file.readlines()`means that you want to check if `x` is a line in your file.

`file.read()` returns file content as a string so checking if `x in file.read()` means that you check if `x` is a substring of your file.